# JavaFX: Resizeable Rectangle: Cursor render

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am creating a re-sizable rectangle. As there is no such component available in JavaFX(it is there in JFxtras), I am creating it myself as a custom component. I wish to show a cursor when the mouse is over one of the edges. But the correct cursor has to appear, meaning `Cursor.H_RESIZE` when the mouse is being hovered over the left or right edges and `Cursor.V_RESIZE` when the mouse is over the top or bottom edges. The situation will be more complicated if the rectangle is rotated by 90 degrees and the left and right are now at the top or bottom. My sscce is below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;


public class ResizableRectangle extends Pane
{

public ResizableRectangle()
{

    top = new Line(10, 110, 210, 110);
    bottom = new Line(10, 160, 210, 160);

    left = new Line(10, 110, 10, 160);
    right = new Line(210, 110, 210, 160);

    setDragHandler(left, right, top, bottom);

    getChildren().addAll(left, right, top, bottom);
}

private Line top, bottom, left, right;

private void setDragHandler(final Line left, final Line right, final Line top, final Line bottom)
{
    setDragHandlers(left);
    setDragHandlers(right);
    setDragHandlers(top);
    setDragHandlers(bottom);
}

private void setDragHandlers(final Line line)
{
    line.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            line.setCursor(Cursor.H_RESIZE);
        }
    });

    line.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            line.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
        }
    });

}
}
```

And I am using the following code to test it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizableRectangleTest extends Application
{
@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Resizable Rectangle Test");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    ResizableRectangle resizableRectangle = new ResizableRectangle();

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(resizableRectangle);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}  
}
```